# Static Method to Graph

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static, graphing

I have created two static methods.

The first one is finding f(x) from a users input for x. This one is done and works.

The second one is giving me problems. It is supposed to graph and connect the points from two arrays, x[] and y[]. It keeps giving me the same graph no matter what I plug in. I am new to the idea of creating methods and don't fully understand graphing in java.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class dummy {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //ask user for input and store in xi
    System.out.println("Please enter a value for x.");
    double xi = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double f = f(xi); //call f(x) method
    System.out.println("The equation is:" + f);


    //creating arrays x[] and y[], then filling them with values
    int n = 500;
    double x[] = new double[n+1];
    double y[] = new double[n+1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      x[i] = i/n ;
      y[i] = Math.exp(x[i]) * Math.sin(x[i]) - (5*(Math.pow(x[i],3))+2);}
    //calling the draw graph method
    drawGraph(x,y);

  }

  //first method to find f(x) from user input X
  public static double f(double xi){
    double a = xi;

    double b = Math.exp(a) * Math.sin(a) - (5*(Math.pow(a,3))+2);

    return b;}

  //second method to draw the graph
  public static void drawGraph(double x[],double y[]){
    StdDraw.setXscale(-10, 10);
    StdDraw.setYscale(-10, 10); 
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(.01);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
    for (int i=1; i<=500; i++){
      StdDraw.line(x[i-1], y[i-1], x[i], y[i]);
      StdDraw.point(x[i],y[i]);}

  }
}
```

Comment: You have to call a method to make it run. E.g. make two arrays `x` and `y` in `main` and then put `drawGraph(x,y);` in `main`.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you! Now I'm having a problem where it will only draw half the graph and then give me an error. Any suggestions? I posted an answer with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Yo are not calling the method in main you have to call it, try creating arrays for x and y and then calling the method somenthing like

```
double[] x;
double[] y;
//with some data obviously
// and the you call the method

 drawGraph(x,y);
```

Comment: Thank you! I posted an answer explaining another problem with the same code I am having. Thank you again!